# How to display all values but allow only one to be selected in Angular Select

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering if there was a way to have a select function as a "listbox" whereas it displays all of it's values such as a list of usernames, but only allows 1 to be selected (ex. to wire up to a button).

I can get the select to show it's list of values via:

```
<select id="pendingInvites" class="selectAlternateEvens" style="width: 85%; height: 300px;" 
        ng-options="invite.userName as invite.userName for invite in PendingInviteList"
        multiple
        ng-model="selectedPendingUserName">
</select>
```

But this also enables multi select, how can I show the full list of values, but disable multi-select?

Comment: I formatted the attributes to make them more readable if that's OK with you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hate to make short answers... but just remove the "multiple" attribute should do the work, isn't it ?

Your code becomes :

```
<select id="pendingInvites" class="selectAlternateEvens" style="width: 85%; height: 300px;" 
    ng-options="invite.userName as invite.userName for invite in PendingInviteList"
    ng-model="selectedPendingUserName">
</select>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry for answering too fast, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hvq3fdme/) is a proof of concept of a mere list component that can achieve the work. I used a old jsfiddle and adapted it for speed reasons, don't pay attention on how bad my code is : I hope you'll use a better data model than just changing a string, but that is up to you, it was just in order to show you the html anyway.

Comment: This should work (allow to select only one), but I guess with this solution then the `as a "listbox"` part will not be fulfilled anymore. Maybe applying some css that could be simulated.

Comment: @Alburkerk that turns it into a dropdown as lealceldeiro indicated.  I'm not picky about how it can look like a listbox, however I can't seem to find an example on how to do so.

Comment: Then I think the best way to do it is just create your own component. You can do that with a directive, but a mere clickable list made with ng-repeat should do the trick. But you have to work a little bit on the CSS though. I'll try to do a proof of work in fiddle

Comment: I just edited my answer with a very quiclky done selectable list in fiddle

Comment: @Alburkerk unfortunately, I'm not using material, nor can I easily implement it.  However, it seems like the way to go is to create a ng-repeat with clickable items and bind it to scope.  I'll give that a shot, doesn't look like the select directive is going to work for me here.